# Shapefile of United Kingdom Constituencies of 1970 Elections

Tags: shapefile, data, united-kingdom

Does anyone know where to find shapefiles of older UK constituencies?

I am specifically looking for the shapefile of the constituencies used for the 1970 elections (of which the results can be found here: http://www.politicsresources.net/area/uk/ge70/ge70index.htm )

I found the shapefile of the current constituencies here: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundary-line.html

Comment: wikipedia has a map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_general_election,_1970#/media/File:UK_General_Election,_1970.svg so you could try contacting the creator... What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you! I have contacted the creator. What I have tried? I have searched google for it and e-mailed some institutions that might have it, but no success so far...

Comment: I just found this website as well: http://www.visionofbritain.org.uk/data/ It should be there under "Boundaries", but I am not able to log in there unfortunately... My university apparently does not subscribe to that service.

Comment: Yes, the data is there and I can download it. Suggest you ask your university library service to see if they can get it or contact the site for special permission. I doubt the data is openly available given the existence of this restricted resource and the amount of time needed to make it.

Comment: I have just contacted my university library service as well as the site itself. Fingers crossed...

Comment: You'll probably have to do some cleaning to make the constituency names match if you want to join the results to the shapefile. One had "Richmond (Yorks)" and the other "RICHMOND YORKS".